# Filter an array taking into account that the filtered options are optional

Tags: javascript

I have a code that should filter the array depending on some condition. One time it could be 1 condition or 2, depending on how many user are inserted.

```js
const arr = [
  {
    name: 'John',
    age: 44,
    old: 'No'
  },
  {
    name: 'John',
    age: 4,
    old: 'No'
  },
  {
    name: 'Bill',
    age: 47,
    old: 'No'
  },
]
const filteredData = [4, "John", "No"];

var find = arr.filter(function(result) {
  return filteredData.includes(result.name) && filteredData.includes(result.age) && filteredData.includes(result.old);
})

console.log(find)
```

In this case the code works, but if I add just one value in `const filteredData = [4, "John", "No" ];`, like: `const filteredData = ["John"];`, I should get:

```
[
  {
    name: 'John',
    age: 44,
    old: 'No'
  },
  {
    name: 'John',
    age: 4,
    old: 'No'
  },
]
```

...but now I don't get anything, because in `filteredData` all 3 conditions should be mandatory. How to change the code to make the number of condition optional?

Comment: You always are looking for the same three data with `filteredData.includes(result.name) && filteredData.includes(result.age) && filteredData.includes(result.old)`, what do you expect?

Comment: @SMAKSS, How to change the code to make optional the number of condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this?

It's clearer to express what you want to filter using an object as a filter. If you only pass the `name: 'John'`:

```js
const arr = [
  {
    name:'John',
    age:44,
    old:'No'
  },
   {
    name:'John',
    age:4,
    old:'No'
  },
  {
    name:'Bill',
    age:47,
    old:'No'
  },
]
const filteredData = { names: ["John"] };

var find = arr.filter(function(result) {
return (!filteredData.names || filteredData.names.includes(result.name)) 
  && (!filteredData.ages || filteredData.ages.includes(result.age)) 
  && (!filteredData.olds || filteredData.olds.includes(result.old));
})
       
console.log(find)
```

If you also pass the age:

```js
const arr = [
  {
    name:'John',
    age:44,
    old:'No'
  },
   {
    name:'John',
    age:4,
    old:'No'
  },
  {
    name:'Bill',
    age:47,
    old:'No'
  },
]
const filteredData = { names: ["John"], ages: [4] };

var find = arr.filter(function(result) {
return (!filteredData.names || filteredData.names.includes(result.name)) 
  && (!filteredData.ages || filteredData.ages.includes(result.age)) 
  && (!filteredData.olds || filteredData.olds.includes(result.old));
})
       
console.log(find)
```

Also, this way you can filter more than one name (or age) at the same time. If you only care for a value at a time for each field, you could just use a plain object without arrays and adapt the code accordingly:

`{ name: "John", age: 4 }`

In any case, it is important that you can differentiate the different fields (name, age, old), otherwise it could lead to unexpected behavior when searching (given you can't tell which values are exclusive and which inclusive), as you faced it already.

Comment: could you, please, explain this statement: `return (!filteredData.names || filteredData.names.includes(result.name)) && (!filteredData.ages || filteredData.ages.includes(result.age)) && (!filteredData.olds || filteredData.olds.includes(result.old));`

Comment: `!filteredData.names || filteredData.names.includes(result.name)`, how i understand, here we check !filteredData.names exists , but  how it works with `OR` operator? after  `|| filteredData.names.includes(result.name)`

Comment: reading a condition is easy, read from left to right, there are 3 condition with AND, every condition is an OR of 2 condition. Every OR specify that if filteredData.xxx does not exists must return true (if the first statement returns true  the second is not elaborated) OR must return true if it exists and it includes result.xxx

Comment: @AskMen when you do that, this happens: if !filteredData.names doesn't exist (NOT operation will return `true`), as it is an OR operation, the second part (`include`) won't be executed as it's not required. If it that array exists (first part being `false`), the second part will be evaluated. It is a simpler way to apply conditions without using `if` staments.

Comment: Another way of thinking of it is like this: NOT "A" OR "B" is logically equivalent to "A" THEN "B". So B gets only evaluated if A happens (in this case, A would be "filteredData.names exists").

Comment: @PabloCG, could you take  a look please, thanks: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63345237/save-data-in-a-special-order-when-click-on-button

Answer (score 0):

May be I can help you.

```
const arr = [
  {
    name:'John',
    age:44,
    old:'No'
  },
   {
    name:'John',
    age:4,
    old:'No'
  },
  {
    name:'Bill',
    age:47,
    old:'No'
  },
]
const filteredData = ["John"];

const newArr = arr.filter((it) => !filteredData.indexOf(it.name))

display.log(JSON.stringify(newArr))
```

And now You can see this objects which consists of name John.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the `filteredData` as an object so you know what field you are checking.
Try the following code and run the snippet to see test case:

```js
const arr = [
  {
    name:'John',
    age:44,
    old:'No'
  },
   {
    name:'John',
    age:4,
    old:'No'
  },
  {
    name:'Bill',
    age:47,
    old:'No'
  },
]

// Make this as object
let filteredData = {
    name:'John',
    age:4,
    old:'No'
  };

var find = arr.filter(function(result) {
  // Get all key from filteredData
  const filteredDataKeys = Object.keys(filteredData)
  // Check if all key pass
  return filteredDataKeys.every(key => filteredData[key] === result[key])
})
       
console.log(find)

 filteredData = {
    name:'John',
  };

find = arr.filter(function(result) {
  // Get all key from filteredData
  const filteredDataKeys = Object.keys(filteredData)
  // Check if all key pass
  return filteredDataKeys.every(key => filteredData[key] === result[key])
})

console.log(find)
```

Comment: ,could you take  a look please, thanks: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63345237/save-data-in-a-special-order-when-click-on-button